# Are there two kinds of n-fold composition? Left and right?

Tags: notation, function-and-relation-composition, lambda-calculus

Let $f^{\circ n}$ denote the $n$-fold composition of function $f$. As an example, $f^{\circ 3}x$ is short-hand for $f(f(fx))$.

Is there another form of composition to denote $((ff)f)x$?

Would one be “left-composition” and the other be “right-composition”? Or maybe “pre-composition” and “post-composition”? And if so, which is which?

---

These come in handy for Church numbers. E.g. $\lambda fx.f^{\circ 3}x$ denotes $\bar 3$.

Comment: Function composition is associative: we have $(f\circ f)\circ f=f\circ(f\circ f)$. Though, in $\lambda$-calculus $(ff)f$ rather denotes $(f(f))(f)$ and not $(f\circ f)\circ f$. Which one did you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks. Would $(ff)f$ (or equivalently $(f(f))(f)$) be considered function composition? Or not?

Comment: Well, $f(f)$ means to apply the $\lambda$-term $f$, considered as a function, to the $\lambda$-term $f$. Then we get another $\lambda$-term, and $(f(f))(f)$ is that applied to $f$.